# running grunt --force on moodle installation on local server

Tags: npm, gruntjs, moodle

I tried to run grant to rebuild amd but instate I ruined everything, all min.js and min.js.map are totally wrong and not working, how could I uninstall all node.js and grunt and re-install a versions that is compatible with moodle 4.2 to run grunt again to rebuilt these files with steps please because I didn't do that before.

I got this error:

```
PS D:\server\htdocs\moodle> npm audit fix

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! While resolving: Moodle@undefined

npm ERR! Found: grunt@1.6.1

npm ERR! node_modules/grunt

npm ERR!   dev grunt@"^1.6.1" from the root project

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer grunt@"0.4.x" from grunt-jsdoc@0.4.0

npm ERR! node_modules/grunt-jsdoc

npm ERR!   dev grunt-jsdoc@"^0.4.0" from the root project

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! See C:\Users\Pharouk-lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: How did you install grunt on your machine ? Did you use nvm to install the correct version of npm & node ?
Also : Did you think to run npm install before doing any grunt work ?

Comment: Yes and yes I did, but after running grunt all min.js files are messed up, I'm using windows, is there is away that I could reinstall the whole thing correctly?

Comment: Also how to know what is the correct versions?

Comment: Hello, sorry for replying so late. You can find the version of nvm in the .nvmrc file. I highly encourage you to use nvm to install both npm and node. Also there should be enough documentation here : https://docs.moodle.org/dev/NPM.
Don't hesitate to tell

Comment: I'll take a look, and try again, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$ npm view grunt-jsdoc@0.4.0 peerDependencies
{ grunt: '0.4.x' }
```

`grunt-jsdoc@0.4.0` has a peer dependency `grunt` and demands its version is `0.4.x`. But in your project, the installed `grunt` package's version is `1.6.1` which is incompatible. The warning will display when using npm v7.

The safe solution is to fix the version compatibility issue. You can use the latest version of `grunt-jsdoc`(`2.4.1` until 2023.7.4)

```js
$ npm i grunt-jsdoc -D
```

The warning will be gone.

Further reading [legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

> Use of `legacy-peer-deps` is not recommended, as it will not enforce the `peerDependencies` contract that meta-dependencies may rely on.